Deserializing BlueSky ATProto Firehose With Generated Clients
Going on suggestions from a previous question on how to parse BlueSky feeds I generated a client from the BlueSky Open API.  The normal feed API returns raw Strings, but the Firehose encodes the data using ATProto.  There is not much documentation on using Java as the client and I am having trouble getting the binary into JSON.  I've also found an OSS project kbsky (in Kotlin) that looks promising, but again I've not been able to deserialize the ATProto messages.  Hoping someone has experience in this and can tell me what I am missing, first time working with the protocol or BlueSky.
Example of (partial) message when trying to String convert it

10:29:49.995 [Grizzly(1)] DEBUG icg.engine.ingest.bluesky.BSkyFirehoseIngest - Handling message: �atg#commitbop�cops��ccid�*X% q ��,#p�G��M�b.�汒�ݓY9�y�8Ybdpathx app.bsky.feed.like/3lcihtx6tzo2tfactionfcreatecrevm3lcihtx6yvw2tcseqE?^,dprev�drepox did:plc:lwytyhp647qpht3ssyxtyfn2dtimex2024-12-04T15:29:49.807Zeblobs�esincem3lcihtlnm3r2zfblocksY�:�eroots��*X% q ٥��7bz�E�k������ ��x�� ���gversion�q �;��u>�A���р(��D��8+؋ �)�(�ae��akX app.bsky.feed.like/3lblkzsgc272iap at�*X% q ��ѭ��N��h�-M�d!@L�   �ZC1�A'av�*X% q V�)_g��V�>�M�GL>kF����wq>���akKchsracrd32japat�*X% q �ڻ��xU��#���}�lB�o��ȥ�A�)bav�*X% q $�L��x��T�30�}_Ψ�
�����&�h|��al�*X% q �|tH

